# asp.net button event not firing when using jquery and html5 required attribute in textbox

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, html

I have a problem with asp.net c# button event as it doesn't fire. In my form I use html 5 required attributes for text boxes and a jQuery password strengh meter for the password field (this password field also have a required attribute).

### **Aspx**

```html
<asp:TextBox ID="txtNewPwd" required="required" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ToolTip="New Password" placeholder="New Password"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Label ID="lblResult" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnResult" runat="server" />

<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success custombutton" Text="SAVE" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"/>
```

### **Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#MainContent_txtNewPwd').keyup(function () {
                $('#MainContent_lblResult').html(passwordStrength($('#MainContent_txtNewPwd').val(), $('#MainContent_hdnUserID').val()))
                $('#MainContent_hdnResult').val(passwordStrength($('#MainContent_txtNewPwd').val(), $('#MainContent_hdnUserID').val()))
            })
        });

        var parameter = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

        parameter.add_endRequest(function () {
            $('#MainContent_txtNewPwd').keyup(function () {
                $('#MainContent_lblResult').html(passwordStrength($('#MainContent_txtNewPwd').val(), $('#MainContent_hdnUserID').val()))
                $('#MainContent_hdnResult').val(passwordStrength($('#MainContent_txtNewPwd').val(), $('#MainContent_hdnUserID').val()))
            })
        });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to your page "runat="server"" script, and there handle your event. Then you can work with required property OnClick

Comment: Actually I already defined the event btnSubmit_Click in code behind but it just doesn't fire. but when I remove required attribute from textbox it is working.